# What replaced usbioctl.h?

Tags: windows, usb, driver, wdk

I'm trying to create a test module for one of our USB devices and I'm using Windows XP with the Windows 2003 DDK.  When I include the  I'm getting a warning that it is obsolete, but without getting any hints as to what replaced it.  I see that some definitions were migrated to , but the structure definitions for IOCTLs  (like USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION) do not exist anywhere.  Even the MSDN help page for the structure still reference the obsolete header, without any notice that is obsolete or any pointer to the new API.

What is the forward-looking and supported way of enumerating and accessing USB devices at a low level using Windows?

Answer (score 2):

The library usbioctl.h is available in Windows Driver Kit (WDK). To download it try this link: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/WDK/WDKpkg.mspx. The library itself is located in (WINDDKInstallDir)\inc\api folder.

Comment: The file is still there, but marked as deprecated.  The question is: what replaced it?

Comment: Yes, you can have the message about obsolete header file, but I think that this applies to the "version" of the header file. I have checked in very old DDK 3790.1830 and there, obsolete warning appears if one uses header file for wxp (btw in this DDK there are 9 usbioctl.h files). The situation is different in DDK 7600.16385.0 - there is only one usbioctl.h file and no obsolete warning inside.